# Why is Typescript erroring on simple interface type merging via 'or' operator?

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror

```
type A = { a: number; }
// Uncommenting the line below and commenting the line above removes the error
// type A = { a: number; b: string; }  
type B = { b: string; }
type AB_ = A | B
const c: AB_ = { a: 1, b: '2' };  // Why no error here?
c.a = 2;  // Error: "Property 'a' does not exist on type 'AB_'. Property 'a' does not exist on type 'B'."
```

In the code above the last line gives an error as indicated in the comment.

It *should* error but surely it should error in the second last line as well then.
Even worse, when modifying the type as shown in the 3rd line of code the error
suddenly disappears; What!? (I did restart my computer - it didn't work :/ )

Can this weird behaviour be explained by anything but a bug in Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

> In the code above the last line gives an error as indicated in the comment.

`A | B` means that the value is of type `A` or of type `B`. In contrast, `A & B` means that it is both of type `A` and of type `B`. That is, if a value is of type `A | B`, the compiler doesn't know whether it's an `A` or a `B`, and hence doesn't know whether a property `a` exists (because we only know that if it's an `A`, but not if it is a `B`).

> It should error but surely it should error in the second last line as well then

Why? After all, the value has all the properties required of an `A`. And also all the properties required of a `B`. Why should the compiler complain that the value has more properties than needed? In particular, since both properties may potentially be accessed? After all, whoever receives that object could do:

```
if ("a" in c) {
    doSomethingWith(c.a);
} 
if ("b" in c) {
    doSomethingElseWith(c.b);
}
```

to work with whichever properties are present.

> Even worse, when modifying the type as shown in the 3rd line of code the error suddenly disappears

You are assigning an object with properties `a` and `b` to a variable that requires an object with properties `a` and `b`. And then you are accessing the property `a` whose presence you have required. Why would this be a bug?